# "In the past" or "Into the past"?

Tags: prepositions, past-tense

Maybe my question is only relevant for my current context.

I'm writing a documentation that shouldn't allow a user (using a calendar) to add an event *in/into the past*.

So, should it be *in* or *into*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In the past* is the proper way to say this.

*Into the past* generally means time travel . . . Into usually refers to entering/movement.

This, of course, can vary slightly with context.

You *can* say:

> Allowing you to enter that into a past entry.

Otherwise, you would say:

> Adding an event that took place in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "the calender does not allow the user to end an event for a past date".

Answer (score 0):

notwithstanding that there may be better constructions:

"into" indicates movement.

Hence, in your case, in the past.